Copy link does not work in MS teams, it doesn't copy the correct link behind the hyperlink in adaptive card, instead it copies link to the team's post
I am posting an adaptive card in a MS teams private channel using an azure logic app, which contains some hyperlinks which are dynamic.
The links works perfectly on click of it, but id I copy link using context menu, it copies the link to the post instead of the correct link.
This is the Json of a test adaptive card:
{
    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "version": "1.6",
    "msteams": {
        "width": "Full"
    },
    "body": [
        {
            "type": "Container",
            "width": "500px",
            "items": [
                {
                    "type": "Container",
                    "width": "1200px",
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "type": "TextBlock",
                            "text": "Adaptive card example",
                            "weight": "Bolder",
                            "size": "Medium",
                            "wrap": true,
                            "spacing": "None"
                        }
                    ],
                    "verticalContentAlignment": "Top"
                },
                {
                    "type": "FactSet",
                    "width": "1200px",
                    "facts": [
                        {
                            "title": "User ID",
                            "value": "1234"
                        },
                        {
                            "title": "Username",
                            "value": "xyz"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "type": "TextBlock",
                    "text": "**Test Link**",
                    "wrap": true
                },
                {
                    "type": "TextBlock",
                    "text": "[Here is the link](https://www.google.com/)",
                    "wrap": true,
                    "isSubtle": true
                }
            ],
            "style": "emphasis",
            "horizontalAlignment": "Left"
        }
    ]
}

when I open the link in adaptive card by clicking on it, it correctly navigates to https://www.google.com/, but if I copy link, the link to the post gets copied i.e. https://teams.microsoft.com/l/message/19:0d98fcce942f4991ab3523811744387e@thread.tacv2/1728979348438?tenantId=37cf0ce8-ac09-4e7d-9ff2-f1da44914b3e&groupId=ba460fb9-32e4-45d5-b1b4-07cdf58e7d7a&parentMessageId=1728979348438&teamName=Test%20Team%20-%20Sentinel%20Incident&channelName=Test%20Sentinel%20Incident%20-%20Private%20Channel&createdTime=1728979348438&ngc=true

Yep, raise it with Microsoft if you don't like it.  This is how the product works, no one here will be able to help you overcome this.

It is by design behavior if you are copying the link from context menu of the overall card by clicking on 3 dots - https://i.sstatic.net/yIHyUQ0w.png. However, we see the same behavior when we right click on the hyperlink and select copy link option-https://i.sstatic.net/65vUDivB.png. We have raised bug for the later part. We will get back to you with an update if this is also by design or a bug.
